# Good software + language solution for as400 scripting

Tags: scripting

I need to automate as400 terminal actions for my company.

I am currently working with python + x3270 emulator, however, some function keys are not being recognized, i have tried multiple ways to make the event trigger but it seems to be impossible.

Therefore i need suggestions on another language and maybe another piece of software to interact with as400 through scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to isolate if the problem is in the x3270 emulation or in the way python is interacting with it? Also, if you are doing pure DB interaction ODBC could be the way to go.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I did, I am developing with wc3270 software. I decided to establish a telnet connection to the AS400 with VT52 emulation and I managed to accomplish the behavior I was expecting with IBM documentation, also MOCHA5250 responds ok, seems to be TN3270 but I haven't found a substitute open-source solution for a TN5250 or a VTXX that can be run headless for Linux production, I don't know how hard can it be to handle raw telnet from Python, also I have to automate interaction with the programs, not the backend, unfortunately.